# Options for outdated WordPress theme; jquery errors

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I am using an outdated WordPress Theme; the developer has not offered updates since about 2015.

It was working great until yesterday. Now my dropdown menus are not working, and neither is my slideshow. Looking in Console, it appears to me that there are jquery errors. This is the page I'm working on: http://www.cedartreeschool.org/

These are the errors I'm seeing:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'version' of undefined
    at n.fn.init.$.fn.preloader (custom.js?ver=3.8:383)
    at (index):754

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined
    at (index):754

Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).live is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (custom.js?ver=3.8:32)
    at i (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:2)
    at HTMLDocument.J (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:2)
```

Are there any options for me to get this theme working again, or do I need to update to a newer theme? Thanks for any help.

Comment: So what was changed since it was working properly?

Comment: As far as I know, nothing has changed. I have two sites using two different themes from the same developer, and both sites broke yesterday. So I wonder if something with jQuery changed yesterday? Or something in the browser? Or on the server? I am stumped.

Comment: Version of jQuery in the page is 1.12.4 but `live()` was removed completely from the library in version 1.9. That method was deprecated many years ago

Comment: So if the page is using 1.12.4, should live() still be there since it wasn't removed until 1.9? And why was it working up until yesterday? Any ideas how I could resolve the issue?

Comment: 12 is newer than 9 . No idea how it got changed to be honest. Hard to help without access to the files. Do you have a backup stored that you can revert to? Updating to a new theme might be best idea

Comment: You may want to consider hiring a developer to have them fix these issues for you if you don't have the skills and/or the time to do it yourself. This way you won't need to find a different theme.

Comment: Problem is that I am a developer. Been doing html/css/php/javascript for 20 years. Maybe I just don't have the skills for this issue. I'm happy to learn, it's just that I don't even know where to look for to get started.

Comment: Ok, I finally figured out it was the recent auto-update of WordPress from 5.4.2 to 5.5 that caused this issue. I downgraded one of my sites back to 5.4.2 and that solved the issue. I'm still not sure exactly how the issue was caused, though... and I really don't want to leave the sites on an old version of WordPress.

Comment: It looks like the auto upgrade and jquery is a problem for a lot of people: https://www.google.com/search?q=wordpress+5.5+jquery+issue&oq=wordpress+5.5+jquery+issue&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64l2.6324j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

Found out in the Advanced WordPress Facebook group that jquery-migrate was removed in WP 5.5. Using this plugin solved my issue https://wordpress.org/plugins/enable-jquery-migrate-helper/#utm_medium=referral&utm_source=facebook.com&utm_content=social

Comment: To clarify: You didn't solve the issue. You put a Band-Aid over it.
To properly solve the issue, you'd need to update the JavaScript code to get rid of deprecated functions.

Comment: Does anyone know of a good resource that outlines the changes that most often need to be made. ie, What are some of the code changes does the plugin temporarily hack over for us.  If anyone has a good resource for this, it would jumpstart the ability for people to manually update their old, unsupported themes themselves..  It seems that the main breaking issues are drop-down menus no longer drop down (so menu items are not accessible), and slideshows no longer show images.  For a good start, anyone know which deprecated jquery functions to look for that are often used for dropdown menus?